# Scroll bar css style in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, ipad, internet-explorer, scrollbar

I've got this problem while doing the scroll bar for both iPad and browsers. The style is working fine with Opera, Safari, Firefox and Chrome. However the style doesn't show in Internet Explorer and it appears the wired horizontal scroll bar on the page too.

You can find a link to the page [here](http://www.calibredesign.com/clients/teo/for_men_test.html).

Does anybody know how to fix this issue?

Comment: This may help http://www.hesido.com/web.php?page=customscrollbar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the iScroll website and demos it looks like IE isn't supported. Go ahead and try it in IE http://cubiq.org/dropbox/iscroll4/examples/simple/. You may want to try another library such as this one http://www.hesido.com/web.php?page=customscrollbar which seems to work just fine in IE.